# I can't fill in the blanks in my code

Tags: html, css

I wrote code.
I can't fill in the blanks in my code.
Why I can't do it?

```
...

<style type="text/css">
...

#content
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

...

<div id="content">
AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>AAAAAAAAA<br>
</div>
```

My site's address is http://www.clover.lrv.jp.

Comment: maybe your editor is set to readonly?

Comment: @MathieuImbert he is saying he couldn't show his #content without filling it with text.

Comment: Blank is outside of content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a browser pre-set margin. Put this at the top of your code, it will reset the margins and padding:

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your height as well. Note don't add height in percent here. For eg. add this line: `height: 200px;` in your `#content`.